# ActiveAdmin: Restricting access of some resources to certain AdminUsers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Because you have to separately register each model with ActiveAdmin, I figure that there's a simple way to make, say, AdminUser #1 have access to all of the models, AdminUser #2 *only* have access to models 1 and 2, make AdminUser #3 *only* have access to models 3 and 4. However, after searching a bit around, I haven't really found anything that enables this functionality -- do I have to implement something more complex to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this gem.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: More specifically, there are ActiveAdmin docs to help you setup CanCan: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md#using-the-cancan-adapter